# How to sort data with javascript each()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have html code with data from database. I need to update this data via AJAX, so users get the new currency rates without page refresh. Here's Laravel blade template:

```
@foreach ($currencies as $currency)
    <div class="currency-{{ $currency->id }}">
        <div class="cur-id">{{ $currency->id }}</div>
        <div class="cur-name">{{ $currency->cur_name }}</div>
        <div class="cur-sell">{{ $currency->cur_sell + 0 }}</div>
        <div class="cur-buy">{{ $currency->cur_buy + 0 }}</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Once the page is loaded - it has actual data, but after 1 minute this data being refreshed, so i am firing an AJAX request every minute:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ajax-currencies',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('.currency-+element.id+.cur-sell').text(element.cur_sell);
        });
    }
});
```

"/ajax-currencies" responses with json objects. How can i put each object with its values in to correct div - currency-1 (has own values), currency-2 (has own values) etc, so it looks like this:

```
<div class="currency-1">
  <div class="cur-id">1</div>
  <div class="cur-name">Bitcoin</div>
</div>

<div class="currency-2">
  <div class="cur-id">2</div>
  <div class="cur-name">Ethereum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you wouldn't use `each` to sort, you would use `sort`. Then to output the data, you would use `each`

Comment: `sort` won't work for objects.

Comment: Your response is array of objects probably. So `sort` should work

Comment: Or you can sort items on server and pass already sorted array.

Comment: Then you clearly don't understand how to use sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need any kind of sorting. If your divs have special classes, then you can find divs by these classes and insert data directly in these divs. You're already trying to do this, but incorrect. Your `each` callback should be:

```
function(index, element) {
    $('.currency-' + element.id + ' .cur-sell').text(element.cur_sell);
    // alternative version     
    //$('.currency-' + element.id).find('.cur-sell').text(element.cur_sell);
}
```

See, I moved `element.id` out of quoted string, as javascript cannot parse variables inside quoted strings.

I also added a **space** between classes in selector, because selector like `.class1.class2` will try to find item with **both** classes applied, which you don't want.

Also, I added alternative selector using `find()` method. Just for example.

Now the selector should select correct div.

Comment: i forgot about the quotes, thank you. Also one more thing - can't i do `element.cur_sell + 0` in order to avoid unneeded zeros?

Comment: Not clear what you try to achieve with `element.cur_sell + 0`.

Comment: Trying to remove unnecessary zeros. Like 4.800000

Comment: Not sure how it works, but if it works correctly - then you can do it.